How do I deploy my containerized Nextjs and Django app to render?
I successfully containerized my Django and Nextjs apps with docker, these containers are running locally, but deploying to Render a hosting platform, I have an issue binding my service to a port, at least that's the log error message I am getting, Port scan timeout reached, no open ports detected. Bind your service to at least one port. If you don't need to receive traffic on any port, create a background worker instead.

Error Log
docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgis:
    image: geonode/postgis:15.3
    container_name: postgis4agro_watcher
    volumes:
      - ./init-db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - agrowatcher-api

  nginx:
    build:
         context: ./nginx
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx4agro_watcher
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - awatcher-frontend
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    networks:
        - agrowatcher-api
  

  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: django4agro_watcher
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/geouser/agrowatcher
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgis
    networks:
      - agrowatcher-api

  awatcher-frontend:
    build:
      context: ./awatcher-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: awatcherfrontend4agro_watcher
    volumes:
      - ./awatcher-frontend:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    # stdin_open: true
    # tty: true
    depends_on:
      - django
    networks:
      - agrowatcher-api

networks:
  agrowatcher-api:
    driver: bridge


volumes:
  postgres_data:

I created a shell script to use the environment variable or default to 8080 if not available
start-nginx.sh:
#!/bin/sh

# Use the environment variable or default to 8080
LISTEN_PORT=${PORT:-8080}

# Replace the port in the nginx.conf
sed -i "s/listen 8080;/listen ${LISTEN_PORT};/" /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Start Nginx
exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'

Nginx-dockerfile:
FROM nginx:1.27-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy the startup script
COPY start-nginx.sh /start-nginx.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-nginx.sh

# Use the startup script as the entry point
CMD ["/start-nginx.sh"]

nginx.conf:
upstream django {
  server django:8000;
}

upstream frontend {
  server frontend:3000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
    location api/v1/farms {
      proxy_pass http://django;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_redirect http://django http://$server_name/;
  }

}

